# Как выключить приложение android из кода?

Tags: android

Человек поработал с программой и нажал кнопку выключить, чтобы программа полностью прекратила свою работу. Как выключить приложение android программно из кода (а то некоторых пользователей не устраивает функция кнопки назад)?

Comment: exit(), но это bad practics

Answer (score 3):

Использовать метод `finishAffinity()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()

Он доступен начиная с API 16, поэтому для более старых версий нужно использовать `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#finishAffinity(android.app.Activity)

```
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            finishAffinity();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Нет! Вы пробовали так выходить из приложения, когда в нем играет музыка?

Comment: @Flippy Это другой вопрос, и решение другое - добавить в `onDestroy()`:

`stopService(new Intent(this, YourMusicService.class));`

Comment: Ах да, извините :D

Answer (score 3):

В книгах не пишут потому что легального способа **полностью** завершить приложение нет.

Прочтите здесь, много чего разного недавно написали по этой теме.
[Надо ли явно закрывать приложение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668047/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/)

Если коротко и в общем, то:
- с точки зрения приложения закончить работу, значит закрыть все активити
- объект Application остается жить даже если все активити закончили свою работу.
- только сама система может объект Application создавать и уничтожать. Все остальное -- хаки с непредсказуемым результатом.
- пользователь сам может нажать кнопку Recent и закрыть приложение полностью (системная функция, возможно только Android 5+)

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: Чем больше я вижу Ваши вопросы и ответы — тем больше Вас боюсь... :)

Comment: @Rostislav Dugin, я ж флиппи. Меня стоит бояться (: