# System.exit(0) только сворачивает приложение

Tags: java, android

У меня есть активити, класс broadcast и один сервис
Я прослушиваю состояния телефона и когда принимается звонок приложение должно перестать работать (процесс остается в фоне) 
я пробовал использовать

```
System.exit(0)
```

и

```
finish()
```

Прописывал в PhonestateListner в MainActivity
Но приложение только сворачивается 
В чем может быть дело ? Как мне его полностью убить ?

Comment: Можете опубликовать код

Comment: Android приложение не может перестать работать по своему желанию. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668047/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось
прописал активити это:

```
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
 android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```