# Как можно вызвать последнее открытое activity

Tags: android, kotlin

В изучении языка программирования *kotlin*, столкнулся с желанием научиться **сохранению последнего активного/открытого экрана и вывода его на экран**(Пример: у нас есть 3 activity, пользователь зашел на 2 активити, и вышел из приложения(onDestroy), и как только он вернулся, его перекинет на 2 активити(там, где он был)), перерыв весь интернет и спросив паблики в сот сетях - я не нашел ответа на этот вопрос. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно такое реализовать, какие нужны функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут ваша ошибка в понимании процессов

> "вышел из приложения(onDestroy)"

В Андроид нет понятия "выйти из приложения". Его можно убить либо выйти из всех активити. В последнем случае в памяти все равно остается обьект Application и ОС уже будет решать что с ним делать дальше.

Вот тут немного деталей об этом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670799/184031

По поводу последнего открытого экрана. По большей части ОС все уже делает, сохраняя стек активити, все что вам нужно -- научиться с ним работать.
Более детальный ответ дать трудно, т.к. из вопроса непонятно что вы имеете ввиду под "экраном" - это именно активити или фрагмент в ней.